# Cannot log in after setting Nvidia's "Force Composition Pipeline" and "Force Full Composition Pipeline"

Tags: debian, xfce, nvidia, graphics

I´m using Debian 9 (XFCE) and I face a problem with `Force Composition Pipeline` and `Force Full Composition Pipeline` settings (NVIDIA X Server Settings).

When I change the default background image and I have these settings enabled then after login my PC stucks (before the background image is loaded). When I have the default background image the pc works like charm.

The workaround solution for me is to have disabled these options and after login I enable them in order to don’t have problem with tearing.

Below there a image with information about my system and graphic card:

[image]

Comment: I do not think this issue relates to these options. Could you provide some log from when your screen got frozen? Could you explain from where you installed your driver?

Comment: I am not using Feroda anymore but I'm using Debian. I found that when I have the default background image and the options ¨Force Composition Pipeline¨ and ¨Force Full Composition Pipeline¨ are enabled then works like charm but when I change the default background and the options ¨Force Composition Pipeline¨ and ¨Force Full Composition Pipeline¨ are enabled then my PC stuck after I enter the login credentials.

Comment: Could you put your explanations in your answer, so it will easier to keep track of your issue? What happens if you do it in command line interface after having log in (you can use something like this `nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"` in a terminal? Are you still using XFCE4?

Comment: Yes I still using XFCE4 and when I enable these settings after login works and I don't have problem with tearing. Even after clean installation of Debian OS, I have the same problem. I have change GPU with a new one and still I have the same problem...

Comment: Which version of Nvidia driver are you using?

Comment: Hello Paradox! I'm using the latest version which is 418.56. Do you have any impression about the problem?

Comment: Not yet, even if I have some suspicions; not enough information are provided. Could you edit your question with the outputs of `uname -svro`, `nvidia-settings -v`, `nvidia-smi` and `lsb_release -a`?

Answer (score 0):

## Remove `displays.xml`

Over here, the `xfwm4` window manager would also fail to start after logging in on Xubuntu LTS. Toolbars were missing and the launcher icons were not shown. However, `xfwm4` could be manually started though from a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> console and than switching back to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>.

That all happened after selecting both `Force Composition Pipeline` and `Force Full Composition Pipeline` to prevent screen tearing. This can be set in `Settings` → `NVIDIA X Server Settings` → `X Server Display Configuration` → `Advanced …` and then saving it with `Save to X Configuration File` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

The culprit for `xfwm4` not starting were old screen definitions in `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml`. [Removing this file resolves the issue](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390433), with `xfwm4` starting normally after logging in.

```
$ rm ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml
```